# pivotal gradle eclipse plugin 3.6.2 broken with eclipse 4.4.1

Tags: spring-tool-suite, gradle-eclipse

Updating Eclipse Luna to SR1 (4.4.1) broke gradle support (version 3.6.2 of the Gradle IDE).

for details see the following gradle forum post:
http://gsfn.us/t/4mm29

Only solution so far is to go back to Eclipse 4.4. or use a gradle nightly build.
Anybody know a better workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by an Eclipse bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122).

Workaround: add these system properties to your STS.ini (or eclipse.ini or GGTS.ini depending on what you are actually running):

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area=@user.dir
```

See also the STS bug report for more details:
https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3922

Note that a workaround will be included in STS Gradle Tooling 3.6.2. STS 3.6.2 is not yet released, but the nightly build of Gradle Tooling 3.6.2 now already contains some code that will cleanup the system properties before running a Gradle build, model build or task.